# Another "NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance" post

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Been adding tap gesture recognizers all week, but I go and do this one, like Ive done all the others, and my app crashes. I must be missing something, but for the life of me I cannot find what it is. Ive been through a dozen or more SO articles on this bug, but nothing helps.

This code:

```
@interface wwfpViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView * firstScreen;
@end

@implementation wwfpViewController

@synthesize firstScreen;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstScreen=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [firstScreen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:firstScreen];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:firstScreen action:@selector(onTap:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [firstScreen addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void) onTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recogniser {
    NSLog(@"tap: %@",recogniser);
}

@end
```

Generates this error:

```
2013-08-01 12:50:11.027 tyrionSwipe[27336:11303] -[UIView onTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe52c4a0
2013-08-01 12:50:11.029 tyrionSwipe[27336:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView onTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe52c4a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0x2dd85a 0x2dc99b 0x2de0df 0x2e0d2d 0x2e0cac 0x2d8a28 0x45972 0x45e53 0x23d4a 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x12ffc 0x295d 0x2885 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I made a typo! Oops. Even without the typo I am still getting this error however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's just a typo
rename your method *onTap* to *tap* or your selector from *tap:* to *onTap:*

and take a look at the target, i'm pretty sure you mean self, because firstScreen is just an UIView

Comment: it was the target that was wrong! many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a wrong selector.
Your created a selector with name `onTap` and calling `tap`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:firstScreen action:@selector(tap:)];
```

use this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:firstScreen action:@selector(onTap:)];
- (void) onTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recogniser {
    NSLog(@"tap: %@",recogniser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your target is firstScreen and your selector is defined inside wwfpViewController. You should change the target to self. firstScreen is a UIView.

-[UIView onTap:] is what it's complaining about not being defined.